# Django update two entries of one intermediate model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a simple Django app, where users can associate with different institutes by signing contracts with them. A user may work for each institute (he has a contract with) and clock their work time.

Now I want to let the user define a 'default' contract, that will be selected when nothing else is specified (the clocked work time will be then assigned to this contract). This I can do with the following model:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    work_hours = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        # We want each employee to only have one contract per institute.
        unique_together = ('user', 'institute',)
```

My question is: How can I limit the user to only have one default contract? If I have two different contracts, Contract A being the current default one, and then I change Contract B to being the default one, I want the value for Contract A to become False.

I'm not sure whether it's a problem I should handle inside the model or inside a ModelForm. If using the latter, I'm not sure how to create a form with all possible user contracts and a radio select, which changes the default-value of the two entries (setting the old-default to False and setting the new-default to True).
Or should I change it to a totally different model logic?

Comment: I think the best solution, is to do it inside a ModelForm, because u can't see how to define in the model this rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to override `Model.save()` because the kung-fu is done one time only at creation time of the default contract

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check if a default contract already exists
        if Contract.filter(user=self.user, default=True).exists():
            # e.g. you can set the previous default contract to be default=False
            Contract.filter(user=self.user, default=True).update(default=False)
            # or you can raise a validation error
            # raise ValidationError('A default contract already exists') 

        # else, just carry on with the save
        super(Contract, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I don't really see another way, other than to make an additional model altogether like this

```
class DefaultContract(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
     contract = models.ForeignKey(Contract)
```

The `unique=True` will make the database check and enforce that there will, at most, be one `DefaultContract` per user.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go a different route and redefine my models, but otherwise I probably would have used your solution!